# How to include a .bib file in php

Tags: php, shell, include, require, biblatex

I need to create an OPC file for which I am using Log.bib file and I want to include it in php without using any plugin.

I've tried using include or require but its not working.

```
require_once 'Log.bib';
include 'Log.bib';
```

Comment: `.bib` files are not PHP or text files, so you can't include them without a third-party plugin that will parse these BibText files.

Comment: You'll need to `file_get_contents("filename.bib")` and then go through the process of manually parsing the contents, or you can do the sane thing and take advantage of someone else's work (e.g. https://people.mmci.uni-saarland.de/~jilles/prj/phpBibLib/) and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @C0dekid Can you please suggest any of the plugins.

Comment: @Adityayadav You can try out this: https://people.mmci.uni-saarland.de/~jilles/prj/phpBibLib (Also see comment about the file_get_contents.

Comment: Actually I want to call one function(with parameters) present in Log.bib file,  how can we call this function(with parameters) in php.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't include or read BIB file without specific library :
Use PHP BibText Library

https://people.mmci.uni-saarland.de/~jilles/prj/phpBibLib/

Or any other library like :

http://www.monperrus.net/martin/bibtexbrowser/